# Passing the value of a variable in a response url with tapestry

Tags: tapestry

I discover tapestry version 5.1. On my `index.html` page, I have a form with a field

```
<T: TextField t: id = "age" id = "age" />
<T: submit t: id = "test">
```

And in `index.java`, I have something like this

```
@OnEvent (value = EventConstants.SUCCESS, component = "calcForm")
Public Object getDatas () {....... return page.class}
```

When I click on the button, I have a url

```
Http://localhost:8082/Mypage
```

What i want is go on mypage but have age in url like:

```
Http://localhost:8082/Mypage/18
```

Is that someone could tell me how to change the url of my page to add the textField content please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PageRenderLinkSource

```
@Inject
private PageRenderLinkSource pageRenderLinkSource;

Object onSomeEvent() {
    return pageRenderLinkSource.createPageRenderLinkWithContext(mypage.class, 18);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these [examples](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/state/passingdatabetweenpages) could help you. I know these examples are for higher tapestry, but I think they could be helpful for you.

Cheers, Greg

Comment: This solution is for version 5.3 of tapestry nevertheless me I use version 5.1

Then the annotation @ActivationRequestParameter does not work for me

thank you !

Comment: I see, maybe you can use this: https://tapestry.apache.org/url-rewriting.html The official page said "Since 5.1.0.1, Tapestry has basic support for URL rewriting". It maybe not the best solution..